# How to test QueryString

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a query string called propID and I wanna check if the passed value in it is a legal integer or not to avoid throwing an error that might reveal info about my database, how can I do it?

In other words, I want something like -but in vb.net- :

```
IF QueryString("propID").Content.Type = "int32" Then Proceed
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Dim result as boolean
result = integer.tryparse(QueryString("propID"), myintegervariable)
```

boolean will return true if it parsed correctly (putting the value into your myintegervariable) and will return false if the parsing failed.

You can also write is as

```
if integer.tryparse(QueryString("propID"), myintegervariable) then
    //continue going along with myintegervariable
else
   //parsing didn't work
end if
```

Comment: As has been said in other answers, you can use Int32.tryparse just as well as any other data type that you may need. I use integer more because of habit.

Answer (score 9):

You could use [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx):

```
Dim myInt As Integer
If Int32.TryParse(QueryString("propID").Content, myInt) Then Proceed
```

Comment: Will try parse work correctly with an empty string (e.g. fail) or will it give 0?

Comment: Empty Strings will not evaluate to 0

Comment: Today I just discovered that although TryParse will return false for empty strings, it will also set myInt equal to 0. 'Tis very annoying when you want to use -1 as a default.

Comment: TryParse always sets myInt to 0 if its return value is false.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use Int32.TryParse.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the 'is' keyword to check the type of on object.

```
If QueryString("propID").Content.Type Is Int32 Then Proceed
```

Otherwise Int32.TryParse would work as well.

Answer (score 1):

C# version:

```
int _PropID;
if (int.TryParse(QueryString["propID"], out _PropID))
{
    //Proceed with _PropID
}
```